# Destroying all sessions in rails 3

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Just want to know is there a way to destroy all sessions for a rails application from the server side. At the moment we have a auto redirect if someone is logged in. I want to stop that for users that are logged in. I was thinking of resetting the security token (in application_controller) then deploy. However I see that from the documentation it raises a exception. Is there a cleaner was to do this in Rails 3.2.0?

Thanks

Comment: Does this help address the issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6837620/in-rails-how-do-you-destroy-a-session-when-a-browser-is-closed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will just change the session token, in `config/initializers/secret_token.rb`:

```
# Your secret key for verifying the integrity of signed cookies.
# If you change this key, all old signed cookies will become invalid!
# Make sure the secret is at least 30 characters and all random,
# no regular words or you'll be exposed to dictionary attacks.
MyAPP::Application.config.secret_token = 'ABC123'
```

Comment: just tried it now and doesn't raise a error despite what I read.. thx!